# ShellExecuteEx on windows 7 with default image / photo viewer

Tags: winapi, windows-7

We have a desktop application running on Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7 and so on (it is written in cobol, but I think in this case it is not relevant).

In our source code we call `ShellExecuteEx` with `open`.
After this - in order to wait for the termination of the called programm - we call `WaitForSingleObject` with `infinite`.

It is working without problems, only on windows-7-machines with images and the default image viewer we have problems.

If `ShellExecuteEx` is called there for a jpg or tif file and the machine has only the default windows image / photo viewer, an error occurs. `WaitForSingeObject` returns `WAIT_FAILED` and `GetLastError()` says: `INVALID_HANDLE`.

This DOES NOT HAPPEN on windows 7, when there is another image viewer, for example, Picasa Photo Viewer, or Evince windows version or JPEGView.

I do not know where the problem is with the default image viewer on windows 7 and `ShellExecuteEx`. `ShellExecuteEx` DOES NOT return an error code!

Thanks alot in advance.

Update:
Thank you for your answers.

@David Heffernan:
As you said, in the case where it does NOT work, ShellExecuteEx has an return code (hInstApp) of 42 (ok!) and hProcess is NULL! (The only new process started was dllhost.exe.)

But, I tested the whole thing on another windows 7 machine. In this case i did the following:
- On this machine Picasa was the default viewer.
- I switched back to the default (Windows Photo Viewer).
- It worked!
- Then I did NOT close photo viewer and pressed "show" in our application AGAIN.
- It also worked (a new instance of the viewer popped up), even when the Windows Photo Viewer was already running!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that ShellExecuteEx isn't returning an error? Even by the standards of the Windows API, its error handling is particularly opaque - you end up having to cast the hInstApp member of the structure to an int and compare it with 32. What value does it store in the hInstApp member of the structure in the failure case?

Comment: What are you waitying on? can you show us that code?

Comment: @DavidK You're confused. You are thinking of `ShellExecute`. In fact `ShellExecuteEx` does decent error reporting.

Comment: @Wolfgang Regarding your update, that's very interesting, but it doesn't change the answer to the question that you asked.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes you're right. Maybe it extends it. If in the error case the viewer process is already running, what could be the solution to detect the event when the user closes the viewer?

Comment: @WolfgangAdamec I don't think it's realistic to attempt to detect that. Almost anything could be on the other side of that `ShellExecuteEx` call. Personally I'd be inclined to add a simple image viewer to your app so that you can be in control of the UI. The interaction that you are trying to achieve with the shell is, in full generality, impossible for you to control.

Comment: Thanks that is a very good idea, David!

Comment: @WolfgangAdamec But don't ask me how to do it in COBOL!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default handler for the `open` verb on images in modern Windows versions may not invoke a new process. It may well just show the image in an already running shell process. And when that happens, the process handle that is returned is `NULL`. That is what is happening here, and that is why the call to `WaitForSingleObject` fails in the way you describe.

The documentation for [`SHELLEXECUTEINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb759784.aspx) covers this:

> Even if fMask is set to SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS, hProcess will be NULL if no process was launched. For example, if a document to be launched is a URL and an instance of Internet Explorer is already running, it will display the document. No new process is launched, and hProcess will be NULL.

What this all means is that the design of that part of your program is based on a flawed assumption. Namely the assumption that calling `ShellExecuteEx` will always yield a process handle on which you can wait for termination. You will need to find some other way to solve your problem.